# Outfile causes crashes with a memory violation

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream, access-violation

I am writing a program to convert numbers from decimal to binary. I already have the algorithm correct for it and the program works fine while using cout. However, as soon as I use outfile in my loop the program crashes with error code (0xC0000005).
Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int num, remainder_count;
     ifstream infile; //define new input file stream
     ofstream outfile; //define new output file stream

     infile.open("C:\\Users\\Arctic-Gaming\\CLionProjects\\working\\Source\\Binary Conversion (Loop w File)\\Binary Input.txt"); //connect the stream to an actual file
     if (!infile)
     {
         cout << "Cannot open input file! Program aborted" << endl;
         return 1;
     }

     outfile.open("C:\\Users\\Arctic-Gaming\\CLionProjects\\working\\Source\\Binary Conversion (Loop w File)\\Decimal Output.txt"); //connect the stream to an actual file

     do
     {
         int remainder [15] = {0};
         remainder_count = 15;

         infile >> num;
         outfile << "\n" << num << endl;
         if (num > 0 && num <= 65535)
         {
             while (num > 0)
             {
                 remainder[remainder_count] = num % 2;
                 num /= 2;
                 remainder_count--;
             }

             remainder_count = 0;
             while (remainder_count < 16)
             {
                 if (remainder_count % 4 == 0)
                 {
                     outfile << " ";
                 }
                 outfile << remainder[remainder_count];
                 remainder_count++;
             }
         }   
         else if (num == 0)
             outfile << "0000 0000 0000 0000" << endl;

         else
             cout << "Error! Invalid Input." << endl;
     }   
     while (!infile.eof());
}
```

Comment: `remainder[remainder_count]` -- What if `remainder_count == 15`?  See anything wrong with that line?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Also, your program never "ran fine", even with `cout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior by accessing an element out-of-bounds.  Since the behavior is undefined, the issue really has nothing to do with using `std::cout` as opposed to using file streams.

```
int remainder [15] = {0};
//...
remainder_count = 15;
//...
remainder[remainder_count] = num % 2; // out-of-bounds access (remainder[15] is out-of-bounds)
```

Once that line above is executed, all bets are off as to how your program will behave.  The valid indices of an array range from `0` to `n-1`, where `n` is the number of elements in the array.  So the valid indices are `0`, `1`, `2`, up to `14` for the `remainder` array.

If you had switched to using [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of regular `C++` arrays, instead of undefined behavior, you would get an `std::out_of_range` exception thrown as soon as you access that element using `at()`.

```
     std::array<int, 15> remainder= {{0}};
     remainder_count = 15;
     //...     
     if (num > 0 && num <= 65535)
     {
         while (num > 0)
         {
             remainder.at(remainder_count) = num % 2; //... exception thrown
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/PwhkaI)

So as you see, your program never "ran fine" as you claimed, and you will have to fix your program so that you are not going out-of-bounds of your array.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the array. I had no idea I was using it wrong. When I created the array I thought that the number was how many elements I want starting from 0 and ending with 15. Which would be 16 total.Just changing my array to this fixed it:  `array <int,16> remainder;`